# Archipack walls only selectable on one face

Tags: archipack-add-on

I'm trying to select the faces of my Archipack walls, but I can only select one side of the walls. I wanted to apply a texture to all the other sides of the walls, but can only select one face to UV unwrap.

I can't seem to find anything about this in the documentation so I'm not sure if it's part of normal operation.

If I use the reverse, flip buttons in the Archipack menu I can make the selectable face go to the opposite side, but it still only lets me select the one face. Same thing if I try to flip normals.

[image]

Looking at the vertices, it seems to only create vertices along one edge? I don't know how I would fix that though.

[image]

Comment: I would guess that archipack is using a solidify modifier so the way to add textures to the 'inside' walls would be to find the modifier in the wall's modifier stack and set the material property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because a Solidify modifier is in effect. Modifiers operate “at the last minute“ on top of the geometry. That’s why they are useful over operators. A modifier can be adjusted at ANY time. An operator permanently changes the mesh, and ends up somewhere back in the undo history.

To be able to UV unwrap the rest of the wall, you can apply the solidify modifier, but be warned the wall will be permanently set in its thickness.